# Since Play framework doesn't commit transaction until request returned, if user terminates request and starts another, what happens to transaction?

Tags: java, playframework, transactions

I know that the Play Framework starts a transaction at the beginning of the request and then commits it by default on response (and rollback on returning error), but what happens if the user does:

1. Clicks a button that leads to a request
2. Play backend starts some doing some action (that's in a transaction by default)
3. User clicks button/refresh immediately to send another request, starting a new request and no longer listening for the last one - and the first action/request hasn't completed yet

Does Play always commit the transaction regardless of whether the connection was killed?

What is the default transaction isolation level? Could some phantom reads or other issues occur to cause data to be overwritten?

Using Play Framework 1.3.x

Comment: You should add to your question the Play version you are using.

Comment: @Salem Just added the version.

Comment: @Salem Any ideas on this?